# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Estou fazendo um site, enquanto testava localmente esse código de conexão funcionava

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "bdcomentarios";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
$data = date("Y/m/d");


if(strlen($_POST['nome'])) #insere somente se no form foi escrito o nome
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbcomentarios9 (nome, email, data, comentario) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$data', '$comentario') ORDER BY id DESC";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    header('Location: obrigado2.html');
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
?>
```

depois de ter feito o upload dele no cpanel, parou de funcionar e deu o erro, "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'", já tentei criar um usuário com todas as permissões e usas, já verifiquei a sintaxe, e nada, alguém sabe me dizer o que tem de errado?

Comment: significa que a ordem da tabela será definida pelo número de "id" (uma coluna da minha tabela) mais recente

Comment: De onde você concluiu "significa que a ordem da tabela será definida pelo número de "id" "? Se você deseja alguma ordem ao recuperar dados do banco então utilize ORDER BY no SELECT. Consulte a documentação que se certificará que não existe a cláusula ORDER BY no INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, acredito que algumas causam podem causar esse erro, vou informar as que acho mais comum e que possa rapidamente fazer voltar a funcionar.

Quando instalamos um mysql em algum servidor ou até localmente ele vem com a configuração para acesso remoto desabilitada.

Para habilitar basta editar o arquivo my.cnf ou o arquivo que fique suas confs.

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Outra erro que geralmente acontece no cPanel é que sua conta esta fora de sincronia, o cPanel e a conta do mysql no caso. Tente resetar o password cadastrado no cPanel.

ord to see if that solves the issue:

"WHM >> Password Modification"

E por último se estiver usando o cpanel verifique o arquivo: /home/$username/.my.cnf

Geralmente lá ficam algumas informações, até no caso password do root e coisas assim, impedindo que você mude alguns parâmetros.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: opa, muito obrigada, achei o erro, eu estava usando o phpmyadmin do meu localhost, quando deveria estar usando o do cpanel do meu servidor